# Ant Migration package.xml Select all except 1

Tags: migration-tool

I'm trying to get the code from my SalesForce sandbox after UI changes have been made and then push that to my stash repo using a bamboo build. However, an error occurs on the build referring to certain files that can't be compiled i.e. "layouts/FeedItem-Feed  Item Layout.layout -- Error: Layout must have at least 1 section". In my package xml, I am calling all members of the layout folder using *.

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>Layout</name>
</types>
```

Is there a way to select all, except one? Right now, I have all the other layouts listed, but was looking for a better way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`*` is supported by the Layout type according to [Metadata Documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_types_list.htm). You should be able to run a retrieve with a package as you defined. You could then delete the file of the member you don't wish to use.

Another way I've tried this in the past is using workbench.developerforce.com and accessing the available metadata. It essentially performs the retrieve for you in browser and you can append whichever members you wish to your package.

Personally, I think using the asterisk and removing the file from your directory after you retrieve it is the fastest way. Keep in mind you will need to remove the file every time you retrieve. Since it deploys from your local directory, so selecting all is ok.